# Align EditText and Spinner in Lineat layout

Tags: android, xml

I am getting some problem in aligning EditText and Spinner in linear layout.Screen shot and xml file of the design is given below.

**1. Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

**2. XML file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/reltv_footer"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:paddingRight="10sp"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_FirstName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/first_name"
                android:hint="First Name"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_LastName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/first_name"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_UserName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/username_basic"
                android:hint="User Name"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_DateOfBirth"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/date_of_birth"
                    android:hint="Date Of Birth"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#454545"
                    android:textColorHint="#454545"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/sp_gender"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
                        android:background="@drawable/spinner_bottom_border"
                        android:entries="@array/Gender"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:popupBackground="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_Calander"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/gender_basic" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/sp_MaritalStatus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_bottom_border"
                    android:entries="@array/RelationshipStatus"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:popupBackground="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                    android:src="@drawable/marital_status" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_AboutYou"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/about_you"
                android:hint="About You"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/actv_location"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/location_basic"
                android:hint="location"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_Passions"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/passions"
                android:hint="Passions"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_Hobbies"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/hobbies"
                android:hint="Hobbies"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:text="Default Feed Section"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio_group"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rd_social"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Social" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rd_Professional"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Professional" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_Save"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#fbae38"
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:text="Save Changes" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/reltv_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#2b4d72">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_Profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#2b4d72"
            android:padding="15sp"
            android:src="@drawable/more_option" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/img_view"
            android:layout_width="3sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_Profile"
            android:background="#335980" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_view"
            android:background="#2b4d72"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="15sp"
                android:src="@drawable/home" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2sp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_Profile"
                android:background="#203b58" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/friendrequest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="15sp"
                android:src="@drawable/friend_req" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2sp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_Profile"
                android:background="#203b58" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="15sp"
                android:src="@drawable/meg" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2sp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_Profile"
                android:background="#203b58" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/notification"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="15sp"
                android:src="@drawable/footer_notification" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the design ,i have used a style for the background of spinner.

**3.spinner_bottom_border.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-3dp"
        android:right="-3dp"
        android:top="-3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I want to align EditText (DateOfBirth ) and Spinner(Gender).As you can see in the diagram ,baseline for both of them is not aligned.Also ImageView in crossing the baseline of Spinner(Gender).Please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: what is the problem ... you did not define it...

Comment: try android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in your relative layout which has date of birth and gender

Comment: In your LinearLayout in which you have added edittext and relativelayout for spinner and image. In that linear layout add one more line which is `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

Comment: or make your relative Layout height parameter fill_parent

Comment: <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

Comment: try to specify the problem you are facing in detail . this will help us to solve

Comment: try aligning spinner to edt_DateOfBirth android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/edt_DateOfBirth"

Answer (score 0):

Try this , while applying `weightSum` you should give width to `layout_width="0dp"`.

this solved your issue , ***i have tried this and got solution as below***

**xml file**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/reltv_footer"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:paddingRight="10sp"
    android:paddingTop="10sp"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_FirstName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="10sp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/first_name"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#454545"
            android:textColorHint="#454545"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_LastName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="10sp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/first_name"
            android:hint="Last Name"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#454545"
            android:textColorHint="#454545"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_UserName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="10sp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/username_basic"
            android:hint="User Name"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#454545"
            android:textColorHint="#454545"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_DateOfBirth"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/date_of_birth"
                android:hint="Date Of Birth"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/sp_gender"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_bottom_border"
                    android:entries="@array/Gender"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:popupBackground="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_Calander"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/gender_basic" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sp_MaritalStatus"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_bottom_border"
                android:entries="@array/RelationshipStatus"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:popupBackground="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                android:src="@drawable/marital_status" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_AboutYou"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="10sp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/about_you"
            android:hint="About You"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textColor="#454545"
            android:textColorHint="#454545"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/actv_location"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="10sp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/location_basic"
            android:hint="location"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textColor="#454545"
            android:textColorHint="#454545"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_Passions"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="10sp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/passions"
            android:hint="Passions"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#454545"
            android:textColorHint="#454545"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_Hobbies"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="10sp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/hobbies"
            android:hint="Hobbies"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#454545"
            android:textColorHint="#454545"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:text="Default Feed Section"
            android:textColor="#454545"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rd_social"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Social" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rd_Professional"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Professional" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fbae38"
                android:padding="10sp"
                android:text="Save Changes" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/reltv_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#2b4d72">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_Profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#2b4d72"
        android:padding="15sp"
        android:src="@drawable/more_option" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/img_view"
        android:layout_width="3sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_Profile"
        android:background="#335980" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_view"
        android:background="#2b4d72"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="15sp"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_Profile"
            android:background="#203b58" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/friendrequest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="15sp"
            android:src="@drawable/friend_req" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_Profile"
            android:background="#203b58" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="15sp"
            android:src="@drawable/meg" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_Profile"
            android:background="#203b58" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/notification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="15sp"
            android:src="@drawable/footer_notification" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**spinner_bottom_border.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="9dp" android:left="-3dp" android:right="-3dp" android:top="-3dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke android:width="0.65dp" android:color="#454545" />
                    <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a static value of height for both date of birth and Gender,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/reltv_footer"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:paddingRight="10sp"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_FirstName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/first_name"
                android:hint="First Name"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_LastName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/first_name"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_UserName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/username_basic"
                android:hint="User Name"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_DateOfBirth"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/date_of_birth"
                    android:hint="Date Of Birth"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#454545"
                    android:textColorHint="#454545"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/sp_gender"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
                        android:background="@drawable/spinner_bottom_border"
                        android:entries="@array/Gender"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:popupBackground="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_Calander"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/gender_basic" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/sp_MaritalStatus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_bottom_border"
                    android:entries="@array/RelationshipStatus"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:popupBackground="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
                    android:src="@drawable/marital_status" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_AboutYou"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/about_you"
                android:hint="About You"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/actv_location"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/location_basic"
                android:hint="location"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_Passions"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/passions"
                android:hint="Passions"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_Hobbies"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/hobbies"
                android:hint="Hobbies"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textColorHint="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:text="Default Feed Section"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio_group"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rd_social"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Social" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rd_Professional"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Professional" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_Save"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#fbae38"
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:text="Save Changes" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/reltv_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#2b4d72">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_Profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#2b4d72"
            android:padding="15sp"
            android:src="@drawable/more_option" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/img_view"
            android:layout_width="3sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_Profile"
            android:background="#335980" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_view"
            android:background="#2b4d72"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="15sp"
                android:src="@drawable/home" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2sp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_Profile"
                android:background="#203b58" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/friendrequest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="15sp"
                android:src="@drawable/friend_req" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2sp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_Profile"
                android:background="#203b58" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="15sp"
                android:src="@drawable/meg" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2sp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_Profile"
                android:background="#203b58" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/notification"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="15sp"
                android:src="@drawable/footer_notification" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Change your XML file below **edt_UserName EditText** like this:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_DateOfBirth"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="10sp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/wifi_icon"
            android:hint="Date Of Birth"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#454545"
            android:textColorHint="#454545"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sp_gender"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"
                android:popupBackground="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**2) spinner_bottom_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="-3dp"
                android:right="-3dp"
                android:top="-3dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="#000000" />
                    <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        <item ><bitmap android:gravity="right" android:src="@drawable/gender_basic" />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```